# How to add a new column based on multiple conditions of the other columns in r

Tags: r

I have a dataset `tt`, and now I want to add a new column `GPP` to this dataset based on other columns `Campaign`, `Plot_true`, `GEP`, and `light`. The case is I want GPP equal to GEP, within the same campaign and same plot_true when light==1.

```
tt<- structure(list(Campaign = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), LM.flux = c(-0.566175215606913, 7.0413933643275, 
-1.93409333494673, 4.19224559401104, -1.68503296181346, 6.22441200764669, 
-0.836688802748388, 4.76271640033768, -0.941060837663844, 6.78320266696788, 
0.566593612955738, 2.44894975513562, -0.295953593124379, 3.313743626086, 
4.49871951303632, -1.88708941334132, 1.93406326381689, -3.92679880777268, 
4.53766548724328, -0.946583109721084, 2.52193436931408, -2.05580682023648, 
2.12821905714729, 3.228610183524, 0.54515934747809, 2.17898943104251, 
-0.512321889888496, 2.38505041390219, -1.27898083550514, 3.79170482094492, 
-2.93690959903995, 3.24250667941275, 0.427821251810631, 0.724538037778717, 
1.42262486563201, -1.21778604422484, 3.03731051269274, 0.287912902986081, 
2.46477866264481, -0.860974384971313, 2.34273627304289, -0.46682518100281, 
6.34481212635648, -2.47605294368632, 5.88326142233214, -0.318547537679587, 
5.94230234685771, -1.5535729406938, 4.90541976913362, -7.53128757308608, 
8.58193105165548, 0.185925227639864, 3.24675828641847, -0.842689124881169, 
4.03121909000296, 4.67719397030042, -4.16782868751495, 5.78607706208878, 
-4.55371022184379, 5.66507279354964), Meastype = c("NEE", "RE", 
"NEE", "RE", "NEE", "RE", "NEE", "RE", "NEE", "RE", "NEE", "RE", 
"NEE", "RE", "RE", "NEE", "RE", "NEE", "RE", "NEE", "RE", "NEE", 
"RE", "RE", "NEE", "RE", "NEE", "RE", "NEE", "RE", "NEE", "RE", 
"NEE", "RE", "RE", "NEE", "RE", "NEE", "RE", "NEE", "RE", "NEE", 
"RE", "NEE", "RE", "NEE", "RE", "NEE", "RE", "NEE", "RE", "NEE", 
"RE", "NEE", "RE", "RE", "NEE", "RE", "NEE", "RE"), PARo = c(502, 
0, 1185, 0, 784, 0, 73, 0, 1145, 72, 862, 0, 440, 0, 0, 329, 
0, 376, 0, 242, 0, 829, 1, 0, 411, 83, 728, 0, 118, 0, 629, 0, 
611, 378, 0, 1262, 0, 1221, 0, 235, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), Plot_true = c(11, 11, 12, 12, 
13, 13, 14, 14, 21, 21, 22, 22, 23, 23, 24, 31, 31, 33, 33, 34, 
34, 41, 41, 43, 44, 44, 51, 51, 52, 52, 53, 53, 54, 54, 61, 62, 
62, 63, 63, 64, 64, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 21, 21, 22, 
22, 23, 23, 24, 31, 31, 33, 34), NEE = c(-0.566175215606913, 
NA, -1.93409333494673, NA, -1.68503296181346, NA, -0.836688802748388, 
NA, -0.941060837663844, NA, 0.566593612955738, NA, -0.295953593124379, 
NA, NA, -1.88708941334132, NA, -3.92679880777268, NA, -0.946583109721084, 
NA, -2.05580682023648, NA, NA, 0.54515934747809, NA, -0.512321889888496, 
NA, -1.27898083550514, NA, -2.93690959903995, NA, 0.427821251810631, 
NA, NA, -1.21778604422484, NA, 0.287912902986081, NA, -0.860974384971313, 
NA, -0.46682518100281, NA, -2.47605294368632, NA, -0.318547537679587, 
NA, -1.5535729406938, NA, -7.53128757308608, NA, 0.185925227639864, 
NA, -0.842689124881169, NA, NA, -4.16782868751495, NA, -4.55371022184379, 
NA), RE = c(NA, 7.0413933643275, NA, 4.19224559401104, NA, 6.22441200764669, 
NA, 4.76271640033768, NA, 6.78320266696788, NA, 2.44894975513562, 
NA, 3.313743626086, 4.49871951303632, NA, 1.93406326381689, NA, 
4.53766548724328, NA, 2.52193436931408, NA, 2.12821905714729, 
3.228610183524, NA, 2.17898943104251, NA, 2.38505041390219, NA, 
3.79170482094492, NA, 3.24250667941275, NA, 0.724538037778717, 
1.42262486563201, NA, 3.03731051269274, NA, 2.46477866264481, 
NA, 2.34273627304289, NA, 6.34481212635648, NA, 5.88326142233214, 
NA, 5.94230234685771, NA, 4.90541976913362, NA, 8.58193105165548, 
NA, 3.24675828641847, NA, 4.03121909000296, 4.67719397030042, 
NA, 5.78607706208878, NA, 5.66507279354964), GEP = c(NA, -7.60756857993441, 
NA, -6.12633892895777, NA, -7.90944496946015, NA, -5.59940520308607, 
NA, -7.72426350463172, NA, -1.88235614217988, NA, -3.60969721921038, 
-6.45438430629153, NA, -3.82115267715821, NA, -8.46446429501596, 
NA, -3.46851747903516, NA, -4.18402587738377, -5.59249455727625, 
NA, -1.63383008356442, NA, -2.89737230379069, NA, -5.07068565645006, 
NA, -6.1794162784527, NA, -0.296716785968086, -2.10135862900541, 
NA, -4.25509655691758, NA, -2.17686575965873, NA, -3.2037106580142, 
NA, -6.81163730735929, NA, -8.35931436601846, NA, -6.2608498845373, 
NA, -6.45899270982742, NA, -16.1132186247416, NA, -3.06083305877861, 
NA, -4.87390821488413, -7.20883910947781, NA, -9.95390574960373, 
NA, -9.26548596696119), light = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), GPP = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(1L, 727L, 2L, 728L, 3L, 729L, 
4L, 730L, 5L, 731L, 6L, 732L, 7L, 733L, 734L, 9L, 735L, 10L, 
736L, 11L, 737L, 12L, 738L, 739L, 14L, 740L, 15L, 741L, 16L, 
742L, 17L, 743L, 18L, 744L, 745L, 20L, 746L, 21L, 747L, 22L, 
748L, 23L, 749L, 24L, 750L, 25L, 751L, 26L, 752L, 27L, 753L, 
28L, 754L, 29L, 755L, 756L, 31L, 757L, 32L, 759L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you also post the structure of your desired data to ensure folks get it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not totally sure if this is what you wanted I tried to guess based on the data and your somewhat vague (sorry) description of what you wanted.

```
# The case is I want GPP equal to GEP, within the same campaign and same plot_true when light==1.

lighttrue_index <- which(tt$light == 1)
for (i in lighttrue_index){

    index_match <- intersect(which(tt$Campaign[i] == tt$Campaign), which(tt$Plot_true[i] == tt$Plot_true))
    value <- tt$GEP[index_match][which(!is.na(tt$GEP[index_match]))]
    
    if (length(value) > 0) {
      tt$GPP[i] <- value
    }
    
}
```

```
 > head(tt)
    Campaign    LM.flux Meastype PARo Plot_true        NEE       RE       GEP light       GPP
1          1 -0.5661752      NEE  502        11 -0.5661752       NA        NA     1 -7.607569
727        1  7.0413934       RE    0        11         NA 7.041393 -7.607569     0        NA
2          1 -1.9340933      NEE 1185        12 -1.9340933       NA        NA     1 -6.126339
728        1  4.1922456       RE    0        12         NA 4.192246 -6.126339     0        NA
3          1 -1.6850330      NEE  784        13 -1.6850330       NA        NA     1 -7.909445
729        1  6.2244120       RE    0        13         NA 6.224412 -7.909445     0        NA
```

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I want.